# NSDocumentDirectory file

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I've got two applications (lite and pro versions) in which I save data in plist file (the save-retrieve data code in both versions is the same). The problem is that the data is different in applications (I suppose each app create its own plistFile). Here is the code for plistPath.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = paths.firstObject;
    _plistPath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userDataPlist.plist"];
```

Is it possible to create plistFile for both apps? Or where I should keep plistFile? Thank you!

Comment: I've no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Droppy I have two apps - in both I save data to plist file. I want both apps have similar data, but they haven't.

Comment: Hmmm.  Perhaps you'd like to show *how* they differ?  Or are you going to spoon-feed information as people ask questions?

Comment: In App 1 I saved data in plist file and can read it. But in App 2 there is no this data.

Comment: OK voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking, is whether or not there is any way you can share database like data between two iOS apps on the iPhone (lite and pro version).

To my understanding, the answer is no. Each app has its own individual sandbox with can be used to store `NSUserDefaults`, `NSDocumentDirectory` data and so on. That data cannot be accessed by other apps, as they have different provisioning profiles.

I guess you can share data between apps via your own server (say if a user has an account with you and decides to login to the same account from both the lite and pro version of the app). Or you could use `URL schemas` to pass small bits of data to and from each app when the users presses a button.

But thats it really. I would suggest just making one version of the app (paid) and just making that really good. Your customers will appreciate that more.

Comment: You can share data between apps with app groups.

Comment: @dan I thought that was just between apps and their associated extensions such as an iOS app and the bundled widget?

Comment: That's what it is most often used for but you can share data with other apps you own as well.